# Search query with parameters in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I need to build a search query with dynamic parameters in net core 3.0.

```
IQueryable<UserDto> query = 
from user in dbContext.DB_USER
join items in dbContext.DB__ITEMS on user.IdItem equals items.IdItem
join cars in dbContext.DB_CARS on user.IdCars equals cars.IdItem
join statsCar in dbContext.DB_STATS_CARS on cars.IdCars equals statsCar.Id
select new UserDto
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = user.Name,
    Data = user.Data.HasValue ? user.Data.Value.ToUnixTime() : default(long?),
    Lvl = user.L,
    Items = new ItemsUdo
    {
        Id = items.Id,
        Type = items.Type,
        Value = items.Value
    },
    Cars = new CarsDto
    {
        Id = cars.Id,
        Model = cars.model,
        Color = cars.Color
    }

};
```

I would like to add search parameters like user name, items type, cars model and data from user. I tried to add "where" before 'select new UserDto' but not always user will provide all search parameters. If I give below:

```
if(fromSearch.UserName != null && fromSearch.UserName.Lenght > 0)
{
    query = query.Where(u => u.Name == fromSearch.UserName);
}
```

it works(on user.data does not work) but is it correct? How to do this in linq query?

Comment: This *is* a LINQ query. Whether you use the query syntax or the extension methods, you're creating a LINQ query

Comment: *"it works ... but is it correct?"* - Sounds like you answered your own question there.  And you can dynamically chain as many `.Where()` calls as you like based on the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
IQueryable<UserDto> query = 
from user in dbContext.DB_USER
join items in dbContext.DB__ITEMS on user.IdItem equals items.IdItem
join cars in dbContext.DB_CARS on user.IdCars equals cars.IdItem
join statsCar in dbContext.DB_STATS_CARS on cars.IdCars equals statsCar.Id;
select new UserDto
{
    Id = user.Id,
    Name = user.Name,
    Data = user.Data.HasValue ? user.Data.Value.ToUnixTime() : default(long?),
    Lvl = user.L,
    Items = new ItemsUdo
    {
        Id = items.Id,
        Type = items.Type,
        Value = items.Value
    },
    Cars = new CarsDto
    {
        Id = cars.Id,
        Model = cars.model,
        Color = cars.Color
    }

};

if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(username))
  query = query.Where(ud => ud.Name == username);

if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(itemtype))
  query = query.Where(ud => ud.Items.Any(i => i.Type == itemtype));

if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(carmodel))
  query = query.Where(ud => ud.Cars.Any(c => c.Model == carmodel));
```

etc. These will work like AND; if you specify a `username` and an `itemtype` you get only those users named that, with that item type somewhere in the items list.. etc